# ¿Cambia el subjuntivo/indicativo cuando se niega?

Tags: ortografía, subjuntivo

Si yo digo

> No creo que el cine para mí sea importante.

`sea` está conjugado en subjuntivo, pero si en vez de negar afirmo,

> Creo que el cine para mí es importante.

`es` ya no está en subjuntivo sino en indicativo. Extraño, porque por lógica debería decirse `creo que el cine para mí sea importante` ya que la frase sigue siendo hipotética i.e. pertenece al subjuntivo, pero no creo [sic] que nadie lo diga así.

Comment: Mi respuesta sin tratar de adaptar teoría ni matizarla con ejemplos. En "Creo que el cine para mí es importante" me da la impresión de que lo está asimilando, algo no tan pensado con antelación. En cambio en "No creo que" habla de algo incierto por lo cual está forzado a usar el subjuntivo "sea"(como presente o futuro), "vaya a ser"(como futuro) y no sus análogos indicativos "es", "será" o "va a ser".

Answer (score 2):

El uso del subjuntivo no sigue una lógica simple. Hay muchas situaciones hipotéticas que se expresan con el indicativo y otras, reales o que se suponen reales, que se expresan con el subjuntivo (“Si algún día nos volvemos a ver” es hipotético e indicativo; “Cuando nos veamos de nuevo” es presunción de realidad y subjuntivo).

En el caso de “Creo que el cine es importante para mí”, no hay nada de hipotético, dudoso o exhortativo en la oración: simplemente se expresa una opinión. El verbo “creer” no implica que su objeto sea irreal; en este caso es apenas poco más que una marca de cortesía. En el caso de la negación, “No creo que...” hace que el objeto del verbo se refiera a una actitud contingente e irreal (“que el cine sea importante para mí”), por lo cual se usa el subjuntivo.

Hay patrones de uso que es más fácil explicar por analogía con otros o por la presencia de ciertos elementos específicos (conjunciones, adverbios de negación, predicados de actitud proposicional como “creer”, “suponer”, “estar seguro”, “dudar”, etc.). Es decir, más allá de que existan explicaciones, se trata de usos automáticos del subjuntivo.

También hay variantes que tienen que ver con la actitud del hablante: por ejemplo, “Si nos **vemos/viéramos** de nuevo, me gustaría que fuéramos a tomar un café”; “No dudo que **está/esté** listo para trabajar”, etc. En estos casos el hablante usa el subjuntivo para indicar cierto involucramiento emocional o intelectual con lo que sigue.

Answer (score 1):

'Creo que' para mí es una suposición que parte atenuando la afirmación 'es' en la oración subordinada para que no sea tan absoluta. Además, como dices, 'sea' en este caso en particular no se dice en ninguna parte, pero también hay que decir que el uso de indicativo o el subjuntivo dependen de la región.

- Supongo que es verdad('sea' no se dice, 'I guess that's true')
- Supongo que me aburro cuando no divagan de nada en absoluto('divaguen' acá no se dice)
- Creo que es lo más cercano que hemos hecho nunca/hayamos hecho nunca(depende de la región, del número de intentos y del énfasis)
- Tú crees que sea verdad? = Do you think it's true? (me suena normal 'sea' porque se habla de algo hipotético)
- También pienso que es un poco más fácil('it is somewhat easier to use' igual que en inglés, 'sea' no va)
- Pienso que eso es algo positivo('I think that's a pretty positive thing', lo mismo)
- Este hecho no indicaría que eso no sea importante('sea' es posible y más en negación, caso hipotético a diferencia de isn't material, becomes immaterial)
- No lo tengo tan claro que sea imperativo(de nuevo en negación, 'sea')
- Es probable que haya usado los drivers (chances are that you used, haya subjuntivo, hipótesis)
- Es probable que necesiten cambiar sus rutinas de trabajo('necesitan' no me suena bien, de nuevo hipótesis, they may need to change their...)
- No es interesante que modifiquen directamente...('modifican' no me suena bien en negación)
- Creo que quizás tengas algunas respuestas.('Tienes' tambien es posible')
- Creo que seguramente tienes...(Acá sin embargo, no usaría 'tengas')